# Real time calculation with PHP & array

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

For a client i'm currently working on their new system. In this system they can create bookings/invoices and send them to their clients.

On 1 page my client is needed to fill in the price for each container in the qoutation. My client asked me to make a new table column below the container columns with the total prices for all containers. I want to do this real time, so when my client fills in the prices the total price changes.

The only problem I stumble on is this:
I currently have PHP/MySQL function that collect all the containers from a certain quotation out of the database. With a while loop I create the needed html code for each of the containers. I made the input fields (where they fill in the prices) an array by naming the input fields like this:

```
<td>&euro; <input type="text" name="msg_container['.$i.'][ocean_freight]" value="'. $quote['ocean_freight'].'" style="width: 100px;" /></td>
```

The $i variable get's count up for each loop. It starts by 0 and ends when there are no containers left.

To make things a bit more detailed I have created a jsfiddle how the currently page looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/cwfmqbqv/

Now I'm not an expert in javascript so I'm stuck at this point. Long story short, how am I able to calculate all the values in the array in real time?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well my problem is currently that I don't know where to start. I've Googled about 1/2hours but couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: Find someone that understands javascript. Nobody here will write this for you. That being said it isn't very difficult to do

Comment: Start with javascript, specially with `onChange()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple addition to your fiddle.

It's not complete as I only have time to make one for the Ocean Freight.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uompg/cwfmqbqv/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".oceanIn").keyup(function() {
        var total = 0.0;
        $.each($(".oceanIn"), function(key, input) {
            if(input.value && !isNaN(input.value)) {
                total += parseFloat(input.value);
            }
        });
        $("#oceanTotal").html("Total: " + total);
     });
});
```

Also I added some `class` and `id` to some of your elements to make it work.

#### Note

For this one, I used `keyup` but feel free to use different events like `change` or `blur`, or whatever fits your needs.

You should have tried to learn the basics of Javascript before you went and looked for a client.

Also, I think you're confused between a column and a row.

Comment: @MarcoJacobs I've made a little modification so that whenever the user types something your application would compute the total. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uompg/cwfmqbqv/3/). I will update the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the first answer, but more complete, and the addition fires on keyup instead of on blur.  It applies to all the columns without needing to create separate functions for each.  [Here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/24wt6c23/2/)

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $(".ocean-input, .bunker-input, .thc-input, .road-input").on("keyup", function()
    {
        var total = 0;

      $("." + $(this).attr('class')).each(function()
        {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val().replace('', 0).replace(',', '.'));
        });

            $("#" + $(this).data("total-id")).html(total.toString().replace('.', ','));

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px;">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Amount</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Weight (p/u)</th>
                <th>Shipping owned</th>
                <th>Ocean Freight</th>
                <th>Bunker Surcharge</th>
                <th>THC</th>
                <th>Road transport</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Container Type 1</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="ocean-input" data-total-id="ocean-total" name="msg_container[0][ocean_freight]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="bunker-input" data-total-id="bunker-total" name="msg_container[0][bunker_surcharge]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="thc-input" data-total-id="thc-total" name="msg_container[0][thc]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="road-input" data-total-id="road-total" name="msg_container[0][road_transport]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Container Type 2</td>
            <td>2500</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="ocean-input" data-total-id="ocean-total" name="msg_container[1][ocean_freight]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="bunker-input" data-total-id="bunker-total" name="msg_container[1][bunker_surcharge]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="thc-input" data-total-id="thc-total" name="msg_container[1][thc]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
            <td>&euro; <input type="text" class="road-input" data-total-id="road-total" name="msg_container[1][road_transport]" value="" style="width: 100px;"></td>
        </tr>       </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th width="50"></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Total: &euro;<span id="ocean-total"></span></th>
                <th>Total: &euro;<span id="bunker-total"></span></th>
                <th>Total: &euro;<span id="thc-total"></span></th>
                <th>Total: &euro;<span id="road-total"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1 question, how would I be able to only allow comma numbers instead of a dot?

Comment: @MarcoJacobs  I've updated it so that you can enter comma-separated numbers such as `1212,33` and the totals also display in this format.  Also updated the fiddle link.

Comment: You're a hero! Thanks again :)

Comment: @MarcoJacobs You're welcome.  If this answer resolves your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is written in pure js in the following update to your jsfiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwfmqbqv/5/)

The principal concept here was using the `change` event on inputs. Furthermore, I didn't change the naming of your inputs but consider better conventions.

In the `total` function, we get a type of columns we're dealing with (using custom attributes is better than just using input names. eg: `column-type="thc"`) and calculate the total number of each related input.
It uses Regular Expression (`RegExp`) in your case to find the right column out of input names. Mind that `~~` is just a simple hack for text to integer conversion in JavaScript.

Next we find all inputs and attach an event listener using `addEventListener` to each for the `change` event type. In this delegate, we find the appropriate input for `total` function and span IDs corresponding the column the input represents, again using `RegExp` but this time implicitly. Then change the corresponding span based on the `total` return value;